# Bash pattern matching newline character in shell parameter expansion

Tags: string, bash

I have a long variable in my bash script.  I'm trying to iterate over it in chunks to do some processing.  It's largely working:

```sh
    while [ ${#REMAINING_PLAN} -gt 0 ] ; do
      CURRENT_PLAN=${REMAINING_PLAN::65300} # Truncate to 65k and iterate

      # problematic line:
      CURRENT_PLAN=${CURRENT_PLAN%'\\n'*} # trim truncated string to the last newline
      
      PROCESSED_PLAN_LENGTH=$((PROCESSED_PLAN_LENGTH+${#CURRENT_PLAN})) # evaluate length of outbound batch and store
      
      # do some stuff not shown

      REMAINING_PLAN=${REMAINING_PLAN:PROCESSED_PLAN_LENGTH}
    done
```

I'm trying to truncate a variable to a max length, then *further* strip everything up to the last new line in the file, so that my next 'batch' starts its processing on a fresh line.  But this statement isn't doing what I intend:

`CURRENT_PLAN=${CURRENT_PLAN%'\\n'*} # does not actually trim truncated string to the last newline`

What's wrong with it and how can I trim a string to the last instance of a newline?

Comment: Use `CURRENT_PLAN="${CURRENT_PLAN%$'\n'*}"`

Comment: It worked!  Thank you!  If you write that as an answer I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this in `bash` to strip off all characters after last line break:

```sh
CURRENT_PLAN="${CURRENT_PLAN%$'\n'*}"
```

`$'\n'` is C like construct that is used in bash to denote a line break.